# Is the relation between the input and output of an arbitrary algorithm describable by a mathematical function?

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines

I hope that this question is clear, and not off-topic:

I have been reading about neural networks (in the AI sense), and the textbook said that an artificial neural network can always be described by a single mathematical function (rather than by an "algorithm" in a register-machine, which is the standard way I intuitively look at an AI neural network).

So this made me think: is it possible for any arbitrary algorithm, meaning an arbitrary Turing machine, to be simulated by a **mathematical** function? (I do **not** mean a function as used in programming languages).

By simulated in this case I mean that given any arbitrary input in the algorithm, that function produces the same output as the algorithm.

Comment: You might be interested in Haskell (and functional programming languages in general).

Comment: What is "mathematical"? Yes, an algorithm is nothing but a function over a certain structure.

Comment: When you say mathematical, you don't mean an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), do you?

Comment: A *mathematical* function is *not* the same thing as "an expression built from +, -, *, / etc." That view was held by mathematicians 300 years ago and is taught today in middle schools (not explicitly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is a Turing machine which halts for all inputs $x\in\Sigma^*$, then we can define the corresponding function $f_M$ in the following way:

$$
f_M(x) = \begin{cases}
             1,  & \text{M accepts x} \\
             0,  & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases} \quad
$$

$f_M(x)$ is a legitimate mathematical function from $\Sigma^*$ to $\left\{0,1\right\}$, it does not care about concepts such as "machine" or "algorithm" or any implementation you have in mind. Obviously the function $f_M$ was tailored for the machine $M$, but this does not make it illegitimate in any way.

You could ask whether i can describe the output of $M$ using a simple function? Perhaps using only the four basic arithmetical operations (we can treat the input strings as numbers represented in binary). The term you should look up in this regard is expressibility, what functions can your model express? For example, when talking about neural nets, the more neurons we use, the bigger our expressive power gets (we can implement more functions).

Note that the converse is not true, not every function can be described by a Turing machine (look up the arithmetical hierarchy, a famous example is the halting problem, but we got a whole hierarchy of even "harder" functions).

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that way of defining the function. This makes the problem trivial, indeed. What I should have asked was: is an arbitrary algorithm describable by a function without conditionals, and only using standard operations like +,-,*,/,^,sin,cos, etc?

Comment: @Programmer2134 I'm almost certain the answer to that is "no".  Already you run into trouble when you try to go beyond the [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

Comment: @zwol are nonelementary functions computable?

Comment: @Programmer2134: I'm almost certain the answer is "yes", the complicated part is how you encode the data that your algorithm operates on. And the function might get quite large (possibly even infinite if you expand a recursive definition).

Comment: @PyRulez Certainly some of them are; for instance, the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and the [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) are computable.  To be noncomputable you have to be something like the [busy beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver#The_busy_beaver_function_.CE.A3).

Comment: @Programmer2134 The answer is no, a simple counterexample would be the function $sign(x)$, which can be easily implemented by a Turing machine, but cannot be expressed using elementary functions (since it is not continuous at $x=0$). If your interested in how to capture the notion of "Turing computable" without referring to terms such as machine or algorithm you should look up recursive/$\mu$-recursive functions.

Comment: @zwol The busy beaver function is only an example of a non computable function, it is in no way a representative for all such problems. We got a whole hierarchy of non-computable functions.

Comment: @Ariel Yes, I only meant it as an example.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [$\mu$-recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function). These are a notion of formalizing mathematical functions in terms of a few extremely simple basic operations. The idea predates Turing Machines and was used by Gödel for the incompleteness theorems.

The short story is that once Turing introduced his Machines, it was shown that they are exactly equivalent in what they can compute to the $\mu$-recursive functions. So for any Turing machine, you can write down a $\mu$-recursive "formula" that computes the same thing.

However, $\mu$-recursive functions may not capture the intuition you're going for. They have some power that ordinary mathematical functions we usually write down do not. In particular they have a recursion operator, which is necessary to get anything like a loop. Without such a structure in our math, our functions will not be able to match Turing machines. The other advanced operator is a minimization one, but this is actually pretty natural in math notation.

A final note: you should be sure to separate in your head the idea of a "function" and of a "formula". A function is just a list of an output for each possible input. It does not have to be write-down-able or computable. By contrast, a formula or algorithm give an explicit method for computing a particular function. We know that the set of functions having algorithms is much smaller than all functions, and we also know that the number of formulae we can write down in a given number of characters is much smaller than all functions too.

Another small caveat is that dealing with actual real numbers and operations like $\sin$ is difficult and hairy with Turing Machines and computability; that's a whole 'nother issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to the existing answer:

> Ah, I didn't think of that [piecewise] way of defining the function. This makes the problem trivial, indeed. What I should have asked was: is an arbitrary algorithm describable by a function without conditionals, and only using standard operations like +,-,*,/,^,sin,cos, etc?

No, not for *arbitrary* algorithms.  However, **piecewise functions that are otherwise algebraic, can be encoded in algebra.**

All you need is absolute value.  It is a little clunky, but it is completely possible.

Take the piecewise function:

If x > 5, sine x,
otherwise, 0.
(Undefined at x = 5.)

You can encode this into standard algebra as follows:

f(x) = (sin x)(|x-5|+(x-5))/(2x-10)

The fractional part is equal to 1 when x is greater than 5, equal to 0 when x is less than 5, and is undefined when x equals five.

I have used this principle (just for fun) to write single equations—using just plain algebra—whose graphs when displayed on a graphing calculator, spelled out whole sentences.  (This was using implicit equations, of course, not functions.)

Footnote: The Pacific Tech Graphing Calculator is the best of its kind and was indispensible for the actual graphing.  (I'm not affiliated in any way.)

Comment: Also note that you don't even need abs(x), as `abs(x) = sqrt(x^2)`

Comment: @TLW, true enough, but with the rounding errors inherent in floating point arithmetic on computing devices I found that `sqrt(x^2)` gives much less predictable results than `abs(x)` when used in a graphing calculator.

Comment: I agree, in practice it doesn't work well. But the principle remains - as some people may complain that abs inherently branches.

Comment: Can you compute the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) with these primitives? (I doubt it.)

Comment: This is wrong. The output of an arbitrary algorithm *cannot* be expressed using these primitives. For example, can you write an equation for f(x) such that f(x)=1 if x is prime, and 0 otherwise? Maybe (I don't know), but can you write one such that f(x)=1 if the Turing machine with Gödel number x halts, and is undefined otherwise? Clearly not.

Comment: @Nathaniel, you are quite correct.  My first draft reflected that better, but I left it out when hitting "submit."  I've updated it now; how is that?

Answer (score 1):

A computer program indeed implements a function, i.e. it maps to the input values to some uniquely defined output values. There are two exceptions to be considered:

- a program can be nondeterministic, meaning that different runs won't generate the same output;
- a program may fail to terminate, meaning that you are outside the domain of definition.

There is a trivial way to define that function mathematically, as the set of all pairs $(i,o)$ where $i$ is an input that causes the program to terminate, and $o$ the corresponding output.

Often an algorithm has a useful purpose and implements a relatively simple function that can be described in comprehension rather than in extension. For example, the Euclidean algorithm corresponds to the function $a,b\in\mathbb N\to\gcd(a,b)$.

Another interesting example is the Syracuse algorithm, which transforms an even number in its half, and an odd number in its triple plus one, and repeats until the value one is reached. Even though we still don't know the domain of this function, it is still a plain function, from some subset of $\mathbb N$ to $\text{true}$.